# Is the phrase "one too many times" an adverb? If it is, what kind of adverb is it?

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases

- If "one too many times" is an adverb
- What kind of adveb is "one too many times"?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is an *adverbial*: it addresses *when* something has occurred.

Taking each of the words into separate consideration, they may have other parts of speech.  "Too" is an adverb, for example, whereas "times" is a noun which is modified by the adjectival "many" (some would consider "many" to be a *determiner*).  As an entire phrase, it acts as an adverb, which is why even if other parts of speech such as nouns, adjectives, or prepositions are included in it, the whole phrase is considered an *adverbial.*

Answer (score 0):

It's an adverb of frequency.
[ESL.com Types of adverb](https://7esl.com/types-of-adverbs/)
Others of the same type are always, sometimes, daily, just once... etc.